# How can I Implement HTTPS for all pages Yii2

Tags: yii2

I want all pages of my website(website and restfull api) to be accessed via https. Following [this post(Yii 1.1: URL management for Websites with secure and nonsecure pages)](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/407/url-management-for-websites-with-secure-and-nonsecure-pages/), I understand that it is for a website that will have nonsecure and secure pages.

should I do it as explained the post or there is a specific way for website for which everything uses https?

Comment: You need to setup SSL cert on your server before you can use https.

Comment: @ekaj_03 I get that,  but my concern is how can I set it in the Yii2 project as you read see my post.

Comment: You don't need any special configuration for Yii2 to work with https, apart from setting `hostInfo` in `UrlManager` config, and even that will pick up current protocol if not specified. Just make sure that your web server works in https and redirects http requests to https.

Answer (score 1):

You might need something like this in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /frontend/web/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```